# searching for a word in a string indexed field in elasticsearch java

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have a String field **countries** of format eg **"SS,SX,US,IND,CND,TN"** and I have a input String field **countryCode** which will be of form **"SS"**. How can I query all the records where a given countryCode is in countries in elasticsearch? I have tried with `match` and `match_phrase` queries but didn't get the desired results.

*Query.must(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("countries", countryCode))*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/query-dsl-bool-query.html) instead:

```
QueryBuilder qb = boolQuery().must(termQuery("countries", countryCode))
```

(Your "countries" field should not be defined as `not_analyzed`)

Comment: @Jamie Caffarel I have indexed countries with type:string and index:not_analyzed but not able to retrieve the documents.
countries are like "BA,AZ,AW,AU,AT,AS,AR,AQ,AO,AN,AM,AL,AI,AG,AF,AE,AD" and I am testing with countryCode "AZ"

Comment: @user2872321, No, the countries field should NOT contain the `not_analyzed`. It should have been defined just as a String in the mapping (no index)

Comment: @Jamie Caffarel Okay got it. Will try removing the index and search for it. Thanks very much. I think i got it now. If we mention not_analyzed will it check with the entire string. Is it why it not returning?

Comment: @user2872321 Yes, if you set `not_analyzed` in the mapping, you will be able to retrieve just exact values of that field, so in you example, you will match exactly "SS,SX,US,IND,CND,TN", and not parts of that string.